# Remove default home/up button in action mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionmode, actionmode

I have created `custom action` mode which visible `on long click on list item` . There is `default back/up button` visible in **actionMode**.

Without change in `style.xml` , it's possible to remove `default action mode` `back/up button` from `fragment/activity class.`

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

OR

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

this may helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method: getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false) to remove the home button from the action bar.

Example:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false); // disable the button
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); // remove the left caret
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); // remove the icon
}
```

Comment: thanks but i am using actionMode = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).startActionMode(actionModeCallback); in my fragment class. And this is for action bar but i am asking for contextual action mode .

Answer (score 0):

You can remove action button home up enabled through ::

```
if you are using support v7 lib then

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

else 

getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```